# Російське слово "косяк" українською у значенні "травка"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як буде українською російське слово "косяк" у значенні "травка"?

Answer (score 3):

Слово "косяк" — це далеко не лише російське слово.

Пересвідчитися в цьому можна у СУМ-20:

> [КОСЯ́К4](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=217575&page=1410) , а́, ч., жарг. Цигарка з наркотичною травою.
>
> Я писав твори на “відмінно” і розкурював **косяки** з Грузином та його компанією (Ю. Андрухович); Мох забиває на всіх, забиває **косяк** самостійно, бурмочучи при цьому щось про човен (Ю. Іздрик); Іноді, під ранок, до лавки приходили охоронці з банку, сиділи й забивали довгі, як травневі світанки, **косяки** (С. Жадан); Коли **косяк** був готовий, Смоковнік смачно розкурив його (Любко Дереш).

Так само використовують це слово й [інші автори](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac11&tab=advanced&keyword=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA&attrs=word%2Ctag%2Csemtag&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&fc_lemword=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.title%2C%23%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.author&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&showcontext=lemma&f_tab=advanced&c_itemsPerPage=100&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BA%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A8943%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22context%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%5Blemma%3D%5C%22%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%5C%22%5D%20(-5..5%2C-KWIC)%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22context%22%2C%22pnfilter%22%3A%22p%22%2C%22queryselector%22%3A%22cqlrow%22%2C%22filfpos%22%3A-5%2C%22filtpos%22%3A5%2C%22cql%22%3A%22%5Blemma%3D%5C%22%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%5C%22%5D%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A1109%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%7D%5D).

Не бачу сенсу шукати переклад, коли слово "косяк" присутнє у різних значеннях у нашій мові.